# Application upgrade issue from GWT-2.0.3 to GWT-2.7.0?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

In my existing project which is version GWT 2.0.3, in that RpcService interface,HybridServiceServlet class and ClientOracle abstract class is present But When I migrate in GWT 2.7 then RPCService interface, HybridServiceServlet class and ClientOracle abstract class is not there. Can u tell me RpcService,HybridServiceSerlet and ClientOracle  is not there in GWT 2.7 then instead of this which classes and interfaces are using in GWT 2.7

Answer (score 2):

In GWT 2.0, those classes were marked as experimental - the experiment didn't pan out, and they were removed.

```
/**
 * EXPERIMENTAL and subject to change. Do not use this in production code.
 * <p>
 * Marker interface to be used with RpcServlet.
 */
public interface RpcService extends RemoteService {
}
```

Instead, continue to use RemoteService as in earlier versions of GWT - this still works fine and is still supported up to the latest versions.